# How to make predictions from penalized spline model

Tags: prediction, splines, regularization, semiparametric

Consider a piecewise linear function with $M$ knots:

$Y_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2x_i + \beta_{21}(x_i-\kappa_1)_+ + \beta_{22}(x_i - \kappa_2)_+ + ... + \beta_{2M}(x_i-\kappa_M)_+ + e_i$ where $(x_i-\kappa_m)_+ = (x_i-\kappa_m)$ if $(x_i-\kappa_m) >  0$ and equal to zero otherwise.

For a penalized spline, the regression parameters are estimated by minimizing

$\sum_{i=1}^N [Y_i - (\beta_1 + \beta_2x_i + \beta_{21}(x_i -\kappa_1)_+ + ... + \beta_{2M}(x_i -\kappa_1)_+)]^2 + \lambda\sum_{m=1}^M \beta_{2m}^2$, where $\lambda\sum_{m=1}^M \beta_{2m}^2$ is a penalty term.

My question is, how do I obtain the predicted value $\hat{Y_i}$?

Is $\hat{Y_i} = \hat{\beta_1} + \hat{\beta_2}x_i + \hat{\beta_{21}}(x_i -\kappa_1)_+ + ... + \hat{\beta_{2M}}(x_i -\kappa_1)_+ - \lambda\sum_{m=1}^M \hat{\beta_{2m}}^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The penalty term is only there during training to help lower the variance of the parameter estimates and predicted values.  One the parameters have been estimated, the penalty term does not play in to the structural form of the model.

Predictions are given by

$$\hat{Y_i} = \hat{\beta_1} + \hat{\beta_2}x_i + \hat{\beta_{21}}(x_i -\kappa_1)_+ + \cdots + \hat{\beta_{2M}}(x_i -\kappa_M)_+ $$